# WPF Best Practices?

Tags: wpf

I am looking for best Practices in WPF Application development; I would really appreciate any good pointers

Comment: We already have many questions which cover best practices for many parts of WPF.  Please refer to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing WPF facilitates is separating business logic from your UI (which is always a good practice i think). The most popular design pattern that is based on this principle is MVVM.
You might want to take a look at it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel